# Sorting by datetime with Redis/Ohm

Tags: ruby, redis, ohm

here is my model:

```
class Thing < Ohm::Model
  attribute :created_at
  index :created_at
end
```

I'm not able to sort the records by datetime (created_at).

```
Thing.all.order_by(:created_at)
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<RuntimeError:0x0000010537dec0>
```

I know internally everything is stored as a string, and probably that is the problem. It just seems very weird there's nothing in the library or in some contrib gem to do this.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what value you are using for the timestamp, sorting by `created_at` can be easy to do. If you use, for example, `Time.now.utc.to_i`, then you can sort the records like this:

```
Thing.all.sort_by(:created_at)
```

If you want to sort them in descending order, you can do this instead:

```
Thing.all.sort_by(:created_at, :order => "DESC")
```

To iterate the results, you can use `each`:

```
Thing.all.sort_by(:created_at, :order => "DESC").each do |thing|
  printf("Thing created on %s\n", Time.at(thing.created_at.to_i))
end
```

If you install the `ohm-contrib` gem, you can include `Ohm::Timestamps` in your model, and it will add and update the attributes `created_at` and `updated_at`:

```
class Thing < Ohm::Model
  include Ohm::Timestamps

  index :created_at
end
```

Then you can sort by `created_at` as in the previous examples, but in this case you don't need to pass a `created_at` value because it's assigned automatically each time a model is created.